# Tell if two 3D cubes are intersecting

Tags: python, class, 3d, cube

I am trying to come up with some code that tells me if two 3D objects are intersecting.  My general idea for this is to get each point on the CubeA so 8 points and see if CubeB's 8 points are equal or to the right.  I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23748/testing-whether-two-cubes-are-touching-in-space

Comment: Thank you so much!! I cant believe I didnt find that earlier.